# Exporting Fusion Charts to Image/PDF in php

Tags: php, xml, graph, fusioncharts

here is working fusion chart demo code:

```
<?php

include("FusionCharts/FusionCharts.php");
?>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>
    FusionCharts - Array Example using Single Series Column 3D Chart
    </TITLE>    
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript" SRC="FusionCharts/FusionCharts.js"></SCRIPT>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="FusionCharts/FusionChartsExportComponent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="Javascript" SRC="FusionCharts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="Javascript" SRC="FusionCharts/lib.js"></script>
<link href="FusionCharts/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ExportMyChart() {
            var chartObject = getChartFromId('Results');
            if( chartObject.hasRendered() ) chartObject.exportChart();
     }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    -->
    </style>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<CENTER>
<h2>FusionCharts Examples</h2>
<h4>Plotting single series chart from data contained in Array.</h4>
<?php
include("db_connect.php");
    //In this example, we plot a single series chart from data contained
    //in an array. The array will have two columns - first one for data label
    //and the next one for data values.

    //Let's store the sales data for 6 products in our array). We also store
    //the name of products. 
    //Store Name of grades for x axis
    $arrData[0][1] = "A";
    //send + char to xml file////
    $arrData[1][2] = str_replace('+', '%2B', 'A+');
    $arrData[2][3] = "A-";
    $arrData[3][4] = "B";
    $arrData[4][5] = str_replace('+', '%2B', 'B+');
    $arrData[5][6] = "B-";
    $arrData[6][7] = "C";
    $arrData[7][8] = str_replace('+', '%2B', 'C+');
    $arrData[8][9] = "C-";
    $arrData[9][10] = "D";
    $arrData[10][11] = str_replace('+', '%2B', 'D+');
    $arrData[11][12] = "E";
    $arrData[12][13] = "AB";
    $arrData[13][14] = "NE";
    $arrData[14][15] = "MC";

    //Store db data
    // Fetch all  records
    $sql = "SELECT grade, COUNT(*) 'No_Of_grades' FROM std_results WHERE course_code ='CSC1113' GROUP BY grade ORDER BY grade ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($ors = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $grd=$ors['grade'];
    switch ($grd)
{
case "A":
  $arrData[0][16]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
case "A+":
  $arrData[1][17]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
case "A-":
  $arrData[2][18]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
  case "B":
  $arrData[3][19]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
  case "B+":
  $arrData[4][20]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
  case "B-":
  $arrData[5][21]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
 case "C":
  $arrData[6][22]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
  case "C+":
  $arrData[7][23]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
  case "C-":
  $arrData[8][24]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
  case "D":
  $arrData[9][25]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
  case "D+":
  $arrData[10][26]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
  case "E":
  $arrData[11][27]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
  case "AB":
  $arrData[12][28]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
  case "NE":
  $arrData[13][29]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
  break;
default:
  $arrData[14][30]=$ors['No_Of_grades'];
}

    }

    //set vlaue zero for othe grades..
    for($i=0;$i<15;$i++){
        if(!isset($arrData[$i][31])){
            $arrData[$i][32]=0;
            }
        }
    //Now, we need to convert this data into XML. We convert using string concatenation.
    //Initialize <chart> element
    $strXML = "<chart caption='Exam result for CSC113A ' numberPrefix='' formatNumberScale='10' xAxisName='Grades' yAxisName='No Of Students' bgColor='995699,FEEFFF' exportEnabled='1' exportAtClient='0' exportAction='download' exportTargetWindow='_blank' exportHandler='http://www.fusioncharts.com/ExportHandlers/PHP/FCExporter.php' id='myChart'>";
    //Convert data to XML and append
    foreach ($arrData as $arSubData)
        $strXML .= "<set label='" . $arSubData[1] . "' value='" . $arSubData[2] . "' />";

    //Close <chart> element
    $strXML .= "</chart>";

    //Create the chart - Column 3D Chart with data contained in strXML
    echo renderChart("FusionCharts/Column3D.swf", "", $strXML, "Results", 600, 300, false, false);
?>
<BR><BR>
<input type="button" value="Export My Chart" onclick="ExportMyChart()" />
</CENTER>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

output of this code is:![image]

then I try it edit above code to add download button to export these charts to as imges/PDF format..but this download button still not display for me.needed download button is:[image]

then I need to get final out put like this :[image]

***I want add this download button to my chart...how can I do this ???please help me frnds.....***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This download button over the chart is only available in JavaScript charts and probably you are rendering Flash chart.

There are a number of ways:

1. Pass the JavaScript chart [alias](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/?Introduction/ChartList.html) instead of SWF name as the first parameter of `renderChart`:

   ```
   renderChart("Column3D" ...
   ```
2. You can add this code in PHP before the `renderChart` function call:

   ```
    FC_SetRenderer( "javascript" );
   ```
3. Add a small line of JavaScript at the top of the page (after you have included `FusionCharts.js`)

   ```
   FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer('javascript');
   ```

Also, you can right-click on the Flash chart to get the menu.

Comment: can u explain more frnd....couldn't understand what u r saying????because I'm new to this fusion charts.....

Comment: http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/index.html?exporting-image/ECPureJS.html  i want this kind of downlaod button need to apply my php code????

Comment: See, the charts can be rendered in either of the client side technologies - charts using Flash Player and charts not using Flash Player but using only JavaScipt code. The renderChart function in PHP actually helps in giving chart rendering instructions from PHP. If you need to apply this kind of download button, the easiest step is to use Step 2 stated in my answer.

Comment: i put it frnd...still not working download buttom displayed...what abt vmy code frnd???is it correct or wrong??where I put this :FC_SetRenderer( "javascript" );: in my code??plzz help frnd

Comment: :plzz frnd seethis quetion & give me solution    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035517/apply-javascript-fusion-chart-exporting-code-to-php-mysql-code

Comment: Probably you need to check the version of chart you are using or contact FusionCharts Forum at http://forum.fusioncharts.com

Comment: i used latest version..prolem is I do not know how to add this downlaod button??I tried so many times..can u give a sample codes to learn me...

Comment: You do not need to add the button. It will be automatically shown when you enable export in JavaScript chart.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21726/discussion-between-robinson-and-sudimail)

Comment: yes .u r correct..but frnd each time I edited my code..it doesn't work for me..I enabled export in JavaScript chart..but i doesnt't work..plzz help me to recover this problem..
please see my code frnd..codepad.org/LUz496Fg ..please try to fixed my code & give a code...
please see my code frnd..show me where I got wrong..

Comment: great to see you have achieved.